# How do I start a bat file from a bat file while the first is still running

Tags: batch-file, minecraft

Right now I have

```
C:

cd "C:\Users\me\Desktop\BungeeCord Network\1 BungeeCord Server"
call "Bungee.bat"


cd "C:\Users\me\Desktop\BungeeCord Network\2 Lobby"
call "Lobby.bat"


cd "C:\Users\me\Desktop\BungeeCord Network\3 Public Survival"
call "Public_Survival"


cd "C:\Users\me\Desktop\BungeeCord Network\4 Hardcore ChampionShip"
call "Hardcore_Championship.bat"


cd "C:\Users\me\Desktop\BungeeCord Network\5 16_SMP"
call "16_SMP.bat"


cd "C:\Users\me\Desktop\BungeeCord Network\6 17_SMP"
call "17_SMP.bat"
```

they are all batch files that run .jar files, which are Minecraft servers. The bungee network (the first batch file) runs but it won't run the next file until the first run is completed (bungee doesn't stop, it's a server, so until I stop the bungee server). So I know its nothing wrong with the files or execute commands, I just need to start them in a new window, preferably in order.

Edit: Taken down for "recommending other software, book, whatever", discords is Blue Ducky#3646

Comment: `start "Bungee" /D "C:\Users\me\Desktop\BungeeCord Network\1 BungeeCord Server" "bungee.bat"` etc... etc... etc...

Comment: @NateC-K I am not sure how you found that link to be relevant to this question? It is not related. OP wants to run a batch file separately from the main window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the `START` command instead of `CALL` command. ([Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/start))

You can do like this :

```
cd "C:\Users\me\Desktop\BungeeCord Network"

cd "1 BungeeCord Server"
start Bungee.bat

cd "..\2 Lobby"
start Lobby.bat

cd "..\3 Public Survival"
start Public_Survival.bat

cd "..\4 Hardcore ChampionShip"
start Hardcore_Championship.bat

cd "..\5 16_SMP"
start 16_SMP.bat

cd "..\6 17_SMP"
start 17_SMP.bat
```

You have another example [here](https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/285905/#post-2762328), also maybe [MC Server Soft](https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/mc-server-soft-server-wrapper-for-windows.19261/) can interest you to manage all of them

Comment: That is invalid syntax for the `START` command.  The first set of quotes is treated as the `TITLE` of the the new window.  So all your script does is open several new console windows with the Window title being the name of the .bat script.  All you had to do was read my comment below the question to see what the syntax and best practice is.

Comment: Oh yes, you're right. And I didn't see your comment

Comment: I used to use MC Server Soft but i was having issues with it glitching and running things incorrectly, but say if I were to move over, (given that the stuff id have to do to the `START` command seems like a lot,) how would I go about moving everything (including the Bungee server over,  I have discord and I would be very thankful if we could go over that. Ive only been hosting 1 server for 2 years so I'm new to bungee. :) thanks @Squashman

Comment: This worked thank you so much, however I'm still very interested in the MC server soft